# Why is a Perl(.pl) file showing text instead of executing the file?

Tags: perl

I am trying to make a simple program in perl. But whenever I try to run my file it always show the plain text instead of executing it.

Here is the code of my program I am working with:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "<html>\n";
print "<title> PERL CGI</title>\n";
print "<body>";
print "hello perl-cgi!!!!!!!";
print "</body>";
print "</html>\n";
```

Comment: What command are you trying to run it with?

Comment: http://localhost/perl/hello.pl

Comment: This sounds like issue with the Web Server that you are using. Does your Web Server support Perl/CGI rendering ? OR, do you have necessary modules installed/loaded for web server which enables Perl/CGI support ?

Comment: i have installed all the required modules mentioned in internet, i have not that much knowledge about perl... may be i am doing something wrong...

Comment: where is shibang line #!/usr/bin/perl

Comment: @akaElement i have edited my code, but still same result :(

Comment: The web server must be told to execute this (type of) file as a CGI script. How to do this depends on the web server.

Answer (score 1):

To run a '.pl or .pm' file in an Apache web server which has the compiler to execute, it should normally placed in a **`cgi-bin`** folder. Else you should add following content in your **`.htaccess`** file or in your **`Apache configuration file`**.

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .pm
Options +ExecCGI
```

After that you should give the **`file permission`** of that file as **`755`**

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your web server to execute Perl scripts. There are several methods, the most simple is `CGI`, and the alternatives are `mod_perl`, `FastCGI` and `PSGI`. Configuration of each method depends on what HTTP server is used.

In case you use CGI in Apache2, make sure your script is executable (provided you use Linux/OSX/other UNIX: `chmod +x hello.pl`), and directory containing your script has `Options +ExecCGI` directive in Apache config file. Typically, `/cgi-bin` directory is set up correctly for CGI scripts.

Consult your HTTP server documentation on how to configure it to serve dynamic content.

Comment: if it would not been executable then how it is even printing that file on browser

Comment: @akaElement To be printed, it has to be readable, not executable. Static files (plain HTML, images, CSS),  typically are not (should not be) executable, yet they are displayed.

Comment: +1. Right said. Unless we know the details of the web serve being used, this answer provides the necessary information which should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to execute the CGI scripts. This CGI scripts can be a Perl Script, or a shell script, or C/C++ Program.

So You need to set up the HTTP server, so that whenever a file in a certain directory is requested, that file is not sent back; instead it is executed as a program, and whatever that program outputs is sent back for your browser to display. This function is called the Common Gateway Interface or CGI and the programs are called CGI scripts.

Again Before you proceed with CGI Programming, make sure that your Web Server supports CGI and it is configured to handle CGI Programs. All the CGI Programs will be executed by the HTTP server if kept in a pre-configured directory. This directory is called CGI Directory and by convention it is named as /cgi-bin. By convention PERL CGI files will have extension as .cgi.

Here is a simple link which is linked to a CGI script called [hello.cgi](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cgi-bin/hello.cgi). This file is being kept in /cgi-bin/ directory and it has following content. Before running your CGI program make sure you have `chage` mode of file using chmod 755 hello.cgi UNIX command.

Code used for this hello.cgi is written below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n";
print '<html>';
print '<head>';
print '<title>Hello Word - First CGI Program</title>';
print '</head>';
print '<body>';
print '<h2>Hello Word! This is my first CGI program</h2>';
print '</body>';
print '</html>';

1;
```

Comment: `Here is a simple link`... where ?